# Log4Net works when a config change happens, but IIS Reset stops it working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, log4net

We use Log4net in several MVC projects, in one of our latest projects it doesn't seem to work. When I do a config change to log4net.config it will continue logging until the app pool recycles or an iis reset.

This doesn't happen in any of our other projects and works fine, I have even copied the config file it just doesn't seem to want to log.

I have tried putting `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]` in AssemblyInfo.cs
I have also tried putting `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()` in the application_start in global.asax

Doesn't matter what I seem to do, it just doesn't log.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Edit: Forgot to mention that it works fine for Logging to the log file, and will log everytime. This is only for logging to sql server!

Comment: There is a FAQ in Apache site about this problem - http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#trouble-webapp-stops-logging. Check that out if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a number of issues.

I would suggest first checking that .XmlConfigurator() is call in the application_start.
Second make sure that the application pool is definitely associated to the application, next check the process identity 
of the application pool if this is defaulted to ApplicationPool identity make sure the default 'iis_user' has sufficient permission to write
to the directory log4Net is configured to write to as you might be having NTFS ace issues, if the location is outside of the 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder try changing the identity to either NetworkService or custom identity with sufficient privileges to write to the folder.

Lastly, check your windows eventlog.

Cheers

Comment: Forgot to mention that it works fine for Logging to the log file, and will log everytime. This is only for logging to sql server!

Comment: Ahh, ok. Then check the connection string, if its using SSPI make sure the application pool identity is set to NETWORKSERVICE and is a valid user on the database. Note: Im assuming your running your webserver in same network and not on aws EC2.

Comment: yup all that is correct, as it works until iis reset. Yeah its all on the same network (happens when its on the same machine aswell)